# How can I specify the committed_date of a Commit using GitPython?

Tags: python, gitpython

I would like to commit a file with a custom date.

So far I've created a Commit object, but I don't understand how to bind it to a repo.

```
from git import *
repo = Repo('path/to/repo')
comm = Commit(repo=repo, binsha=repo.head.commit.binsha, tree=repo.index.write_tree(), message='Test Message', committed_date=1357020000)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found the solution.

I wasn't aware, but I had to provide **all** the parameters otherwise the Commit object would throw a BadObject exception when trying to serialize it.

```
from git import *
from time import (time, altzone)
import datetime
from cStringIO import StringIO
from gitdb import IStream

repo = Repo('path/to/repo')

message = 'Commit message'

tree = repo.index.write_tree()
parents = [ repo.head.commit ]

# Committer and Author
cr = repo.config_reader()
committer = Actor.committer(cr)
author = Actor.author(cr)

# Custom Date
time = int(datetime.date(2013, 1, 1).strftime('%s'))
offset = altzone
author_time, author_offset = time, offset
committer_time, committer_offset = time, offset

# UTF-8 Default
conf_encoding = 'UTF-8'

comm = Commit(repo, Commit.NULL_BIN_SHA, tree, 
      author, author_time, author_offset, 
      committer, committer_time, committer_offset,
      message, parents, conf_encoding)
```

After creating the commit object, a proper SHA had to be placed, I didn't have a clue how this was done, but a little bit of research in the guts of GitPython source code got me the answer.

```
stream = StringIO()
new_commit._serialize(stream)
streamlen = stream.tell()
stream.seek(0)

istream = repo.odb.store(IStream(Commit.type, streamlen, stream))
new_commit.binsha = istream.binsha
```

Then set the commit as the HEAD commit

```
repo.head.set_commit(new_commit, logmsg="commit: %s" % message)
```

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution, which avoids having to manually create commit objects (And also manually create new indexes, if you wanted to add files too):

```py
from git import Repo, Actor # GitPython
import git.exc as GitExceptions # GitPython
import os # Python Core


# Example values
respository_directory = "."
new_file_path = "MyNewFile"
action_date = str(datetime.date(2013, 1, 1))
message = "I am a commit log! See commit log run. Run! Commit log! Run!"
actor = Actor("Bob", "Bob@McTesterson.dev" )

# Open repository
try:
    repo = Repo(respository_directory)
except GitExceptions.InvalidGitRepositoryError:
    print "Error: %s isn't a git repo" % respository_directory
    sys.exit(5)

# Set some environment variables, the repo.index commit function
# pays attention to these.
os.environ["GIT_AUTHOR_DATE"] = action_date
os.environ["GIT_COMMITTER_DATE"] = action_date

# Add your new file/s
repo.index.add([new_file_path])

# Do the commit thing.
repo.index.commit(message, author=actor, committer=actor)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set `commit_date` when making the commit.

```
r.index.commit(
    "Initial Commit",
    commit_date=datetime.date(2020, 7, 21).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also using specified date/time for committing purpose. In my case after a long research I have figured out, that you have to give the `datetime` not really in ISO format as GitPython suggests you should, nor in `timestamp` format. It is actually making delusion because of its own "parsing" that is should be a standard python format.

Nope. You have to give it in the format that git itself would understand.

For example:

```
# commit_date is your specified date in datetime format
commit_date_as_text = commit_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')
git_repository.index.commit(commit_message, author=commit_author, commit_date=commit_date_as_text)
```

List of accepted formats you can find for example in [another topic on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19742762/1960514).