# git commit -ac <commit_id> does not use latest date

Tags: git

I am trying to use `git commit -ac <commit_id>` to perform a new commit. However I see that the date and time is used for the new commit is that of the previous commit_id that I pass. Is there a way that it can use the current date and time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--reset-author` option may do what you want, though it also resets author (if you were not the author of original commit) along with the commit timestamp. From `git help commit`:

```
--reset-author
      When used with -C/-c/--amend options, or when committing after a
      conflicting cherry-pick, declare that the authorship of the
      resulting commit now belongs of the committer. 
      This also renews the author timestamp.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use  the `--date` flag.

`--date=<date>

Override the author date used in the commit`

[This question shows the various date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742345/what-is-the-format-for-date-parameter-of-git-commit) that you can use.

See the documentation for Git using `git help commit` or at http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit.

Also, I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but it you want to amend something that is wrong with the previous commit, you can do `git commit --amend` to add/remove files or change the commit message if you haven't already pushed to any remotes.

Comment: I am trying to use the commit message from a previous commit I made, but when I use the `-c` option it was picking up the time and date of the original commit. I wanted it to pick the current time and date. Using `--reset-author` helped.

Comment: Does the --date flag work? Seems strange to reset the author when all you want to do is reset the date.

Comment: I did not try, it might work. But I do not want to specify the date explicitly. I wanted git to pick up the current date and time.

Comment: Ok. I can understand that.