# Is it possible to set a git commit to have a timestamp prior to 1970?

Tags: git, timestamp, epoch, git-commit

Unix timestamps are signed 32 bit integers (64 bit on some systems today, or so I understand). On some software products this allows you to use dates going back as far as 1903 or so.

However, when I try the following:

```
git commit -m "this is a test commit" --date="1960-04-07 18:00:00"
```

I receive an "fatal: invalid date format" error.

This isn't very practical (I'm not a time-traveler), but I've been wondering about using git for historical purposes. Can this be forced with a git plumbing command? On a related note: does git always use a 32 bit timestamp, or does this depend on the environment it's built on?

Comment: Actually, if this worked, it would be very practical for some people trying to put law code into source control, for instance [this repo](https://github.com/steeve/france.code-civil/commits/master?after=159d0518486cba8b3777c12380ecf1787887fbfc+174)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As far back as [commit c64b9b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c64b9b88605f9d6824bf953a84d993c4a70fd759) (git 0.99, May 2005), time has always been referred as

```
<date>
```

> Date in 'seconds since [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)'

[commit 6eb8ae0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6eb8ae00d4bceaf660a07d8bc5ab8d6ddccbe1af)  defines date as an `unsigned long` since April 2005.

### TLDR;

### date before unix epoch can be stored, but cannot be sure to be correctly represented.

But that has evolved since 2014 (see at the end)

---

Trying to represent a date *before* has been attempted before: see [this thread](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/236827)

> The date I'm trying to set is October 4, 1958, that is around timestamp -354808800.
>
> First technique, using the commit `--date` flags with ISO 8601: it says
>   "`invalid date`".
>
> Second technique, described in the [git ml archive](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/152497/), not using the porcelain:

```
git commit
git cat-file -p HEAD > tmp.txt
# at this point, edit the file to replace the timestamp

git hash-object -t commit -w tmp.txt
#=> 2ee8fcc02658e23219143f5bcfe6f9a4615745f9
git update-ref -m 'commit: foo' refs/heads/master \
    2ee8fcc02658e23219143f5bcfe6f9a4615745f9
```

> Commit date is effectively updated, but `git show` clamps the date to zero (`Jan 1 1970`). `tig(1)` displays `55 years ago` so the actual commit date is properly stored.
>
> Last issue: when trying to push this commit to a remote repository:

```
#=> remote: error: object 2ee8fcc02658e23219143f5bcfe6f9a4615745f9:invalid
#       author/committer line - bad date
#=> remote: fatal: Error in object
#=> error: unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
```

> Finally, when running `test-date` from git sources:

```
./test-date show -354808800
#=> -354808800 -> in the future
```

---

The [discussion at the time](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/152433/focus=152497) mentioned:

> I am not sure there isn't some unportability at the lowest level.
>   We freely interchange between time_t and unsigned long in the low-level date code. It probably happens to work because casting the bits back and forth between signed and unsigned types generally works, as long as you end up with the type that you want.
>   But it isn't necessarily portable, and there can be subtle bugs. [See, for example, my recent 9ba0f033](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ba0f0334dd505f78e0374bbe857c5e202f5a778).
>
> The good news that this is purely a code problem. The data format is fine. It would just take somebody going through the code and switching all "`unsigned long`" to "`long long`" (or `time_t`, or even "`gittime_t`" if we want to abstract it).
>
> and fixing the parser algorithm at least in `tm_to_time_t()`
>
> It is *not* just "`sed s/unsigned long/long long`", but rather checking every change to make sure that you aren't introducing new bugs, and that the code correctly handles signed
>   types.
>   Which is why nobody has done it. ;)

---

As I mentioned in 2017, in "[Use future date while making git commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44034105/6309)", Git has started to adopt a different and dedicated `timestamp_t` type.

As illustrated in [Legilibre/Archeo-Lex issue 47](https://github.com/Legilibre/Archeo-Lex/issues/47#issuecomment-354783071):

> Dates are now using the `timestamp_t` type, defined as `typedef uintmax_t timestamp_t;`, in place of `unsigned long` type, in order to fix some issues on 32bits platforms... and Windows 64 bits ^^.

The project [archeo-lex.fr](https://archeo-lex.fr/) (which depends on older dates) is using git hash-object, combined with the Git repo viewer [`Legilibre/Archeo-Lex-web`](https://github.com/Legilibre/Archeo-Lex-web).
This is now (Feb. 2019) done, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787872/is-it-possible-to-set-a-git-commit-to-have-a-timestamp-prior-to-1970/24977895#comment96017232_24977895) by [Seb35](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1078843/seb35)

Comment: Thanks. I use this to put the French law into Git on https://archeo-lex.fr. The repos have the dates pre-1970 (1803 for the older, the Civil Code) and post-2100. Note that GitHub and Gitlab reject the repos.
The Python code creating the repos [is there](https://github.com/Legilibre/Archeo-Lex/blob/3a4a481a9fe9436f632981fa84d3f37bcd10e018/marcheolex/exporterlegi.py#L491-L498). I also adapted the PHP web interface, see [this commit](https://github.com/Legilibre/Archeo-Lex-web/commit/b6899accade52ac8cd2ec7727e49029daa994320). I also had fun with old timezones because they didn’t exist in 1803.

Comment: @Seb35 Great! I have included a reference to your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @Seb35 That's pretty awesome. Are there any standards for even how to use git for statutes/legislation? In the US, when a law is repealed that doesn't mean the text is removed, it's sort of "commented out" by the statute repealing it. It'd be sort of weird to see the Constitution with the 18th amendment just missing...

Comment: @JohnO This is diverging from the original question. I don’t know standards for Git in this use case, it’s still experimental but I know it was also experimented on the Chinese constitution. Question repealed texts is a legal question instead of technical, you can read about the consolidation operation but it seems it is not usually used for the US Constitution.

Answer (score 3):

Git internally maintains dates as a Unix timestamp and an offset from UTC, so it is not possible to set a commit date before the Unix time epoch.

You must be running a different version of Git than I have on my CentOS 6.5 system (which provides Git 1.7.1), at least yours gives you an error message...  If I try to set an impossible commit date using Git 1.7.1, the commit succeeds and silently uses the current time for the commit date; if I try the same operation using a "possible" commit date, it succeeds and records the intended commit date.

Comment: The unix timestamp is a signed 32 bit integer. Negative numbers correspond as one would think, and since you get 2.something billion of them and 2 billion seconds is about 64 years, you should be able to go back to 1906 plus change. Or so I understand. Does anything even use an unsigned int for timestamps?

Comment: Looking in the source code, it appears that the commit date is recorded in the commit structure as an unsigned long:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/commit.h

Comment: And I'll admit, I never have thought about the idea of time_t being signed meaning that dates before the epoch could be represented, so technically this would appear to be a bug in Git (or, at least, a documentation inaccuracy....)

Answer (score 3):

You could store them, but nothing would show them like you expected (yet).

The internal Git format stores the commit data as a numeric string. e.g.:

```
$ git cat-file -p aa2706463fdeb51d6f9d0e267113b251888cf7f5
...
author Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1383318892 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1383318892 -0700
```

I don't believe that it's required that this number be positive. However, most implementations, including `git`, parse it as an unsigned number and won't display those dates correctly. For example, [in `builtin/blame.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5f95c9f850b19b368c43ae399cc831b17a26a5ac/builtin/blame.c#L1345):

```
    *time = strtoul(ident.date_begin, NULL, 10);
```

So; using negative times isn't something you can easily do with current tools, or display with current tools, but Git's model means that commits including them would survive unchanged in a repository.

Answer (score 1):

I just twiddled around with git hash-object and created the following commit object:

```
tree 5efb9bc29c482e023e40e0a2b3b7e49cec842034
author x <x@x.com> -134607600 -0500
committer z <z@z.com> 1402404632 -0600

blah blah
```

You'll note that the author date is set to a negative number. I then used git update-ref to try to link the commit object in... no luck, I get the following output when I do a git log:

```
$ git log
commit 2303e7012001a3cc1c3dec806d0902008e1257a8
Author: x <x@x.com>
Date:   (null)

    blah blah
```

Sourcetree is similarly confused:

```
Parents: 
Author: x <x@x.com>
Date: Monday, January 01, 0001 12:00:00 AM
Committer: z <z@z.com>
Commit Date: Tuesday, June 10, 2014 7:50:32 AM
```

(I think I forgot to include the parent commit object...)

Similarly, dates in the far future do not work either (indicating that it probably isn't treating this as a 64 bit value even if it is one).

I'm not sure if this answer qualifies as a "no you cannot do this" or a "you can, but it doesn't work well". One would need an modified client to be able to see the git logs with correct dates, removing any possible benefit for this. If someone knows a nifty git log command that would parse those timestamps correctly (are they gone at that point?!?!) please correct me.