# What date formats does git log accept for date parameters?

Tags: git, date, timezone

What date formats does `git log` accept for the `--before`, `--after`, `--since`, and `--until` options (as opposed to the `--date` option)?

I'm interested in getting logs for date ranges in the local time zone.

Comment: Unix epoch time (seconds since 0:00 Jan 1 1970 UTC) appears to be supported.  Some more info: http://alexpeattie.com/blog/working-with-dates-in-git/#date-parsing-with-approxidate

Comment: Consider using `git log --date=local` also.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/24977895/6309

Comment: See also the table under format in [git log documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) (search for "format-string" or "placeholders"), as well as [How to change Git log date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853332/how-to-change-git-log-date-formats)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/date-formats.txt) these formats are accepted:

- Git internal format::
  It is `<unix timestamp> <time zone offset>`, where `<unix
  timestamp>` is the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch.
  `<time zone offset>` is a positive or negative offset from UTC.
  For example CET (which is 2 hours ahead UTC) is `+0200`.
- RFC 2822::
  The standard email format as described by RFC 2822, for example
  `Thu, 07 Apr 2005 22:13:13 +0200`.
- ISO 8601::
  Time and date specified by the ISO 8601 standard, for example
  `2005-04-07T22:13:13`. The parser accepts a space instead of the
  `T` character as well.
- +
  NOTE: In addition, the date part is accepted in the following formats:
  `YYYY.MM.DD`, `MM/DD/YYYY` and `DD.MM.YYYY`.