# Total number of commits on git/GitHub in a specific timeframe?

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit

How can I know the total number of commits done on a project through the GitHub web interface? ***How can I get the total number of commits in a specific time frame?***

What I can get now is the number of commits done by each developer, not the total one.

Example: [https://github.com/BVLC/caffe](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/graphs/contributors?from=2013-09-08&to=2016-12-24&type=c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get to the compare view, append /compare to your repository's path. Every repository's Compare view contains two drop down menus: base and compare

To compare the commits in timeframe you can do type the branch name in the compare dropdown, followed by a `@`, and then the date wrapped between a `{ }` notation.

Here are two examples:

[Date Compairson](https://github.com/octo-org/wikimania/compare/master@%7B07-22-16%7D...master@%7B08-04-16%7D)

[Time entered in Weeks](https://github.com/octo-org/wikimania/compare/master@%7B2weeks%7D...master)

**Source**: https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/

**Commits Done Using GitHub Web Interface:**

Commits are commits whether you do it from the `git` interface or web interface. I guess there is no way to identify it.

**Commits done by each developer:**

It is clearly mentioned in the link you provided:

[Contributors](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/graphs/contributors)

Comment: It works. A detail: I saw no "compare" link on the main GithHub web page, I had to add it manually to the URL.

Comment: If you click on 'New Pull Request' it will open up the same page.

Answer (score 8):

As your tags and question line don't limit this to just the GitHub interface, you can get what you want from the command line:

```
$ git rev-list --count master --since=5.months
577
$ git rev-list --count master --since=4.months
524
```

As well as `--since` it supports `--until` to specify a full range. 
[Manual Reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list).

See also, [What date formats does git log accept for date parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090617/what-date-formats-does-git-log-accept-for-date-parameters)

Answer (score 4):

You can get total number of commits through a time period with two different ways

### First way

Using since and before - since take the start date and before take the end date that you want to get commit from it.

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD --since="Dec 1 2021"  --before="Jan 3 2022"
```

### Second way

Get the total commit by using [second - hour - day - week - month - year]

> Get the total commits by second

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD  --since=600.second
```

> Get the total commits by minute

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD  --since=30.minute
```

> Get the total commits by day

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD  --since=28.day
```

> Get the total commits by week

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD  --since=4.week
```

> Get the total commits by month

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD  --since=1.month
```

> Get the total commits by year

```bash
git rev-list --count HEAD  --since=2.year
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears on the project's main page, in the top left corner:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `https://github.com/USER_NAME/REPOSITORY`. In you case, you have to go to https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.

After visiting the above mentioned page, you can see the `total number of commits`. Refer the picture below:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the timeframe question.