# Can git represent commit dates before 1970?

Tags: git, date

The project [france.code-civil](https://github.com/steeve/france.code-civil) encodes the entire history of the French *[Code Civil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleonic_Code)* in a git repository, with law amendments being represented as commits.

The *Code* dates back to 1804, and in the current repository all commit dates before the UNIX epoch are clipped to the start of the epoch, i.e. January 1, 1970, or a UNIX timestamp of zero.

Is this a limitation of the git system itself? Can git (internally) represent commit dates before 1970 (negative timestamps, alternative date formats)? If yes, how can such a commit be created?

Comment: I already answered that last year: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24977895/6309