# How does Git parse the dates?

Tags: git, epoch

I'm trying to make a commit before the epoch time but it seems that if I'm doing so, `git` says the date is sometime in 2014:

```
$ git commit -m 'Minor' --date 'Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 1969 +0000' . --amend
[master 4d1ea4d] Minor
 Date: Tue Dec 30 23:00:00 2014 +0200
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
```

However it does work if I make the commit in the epoch time:

```
$ git commit -m 'Minor' --date 'Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970 +0000' . --amend
[master d0623ee] Minor
 Date: Thu Jan 1 00:00:00 1970 +0000
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+)
```

Why? How can I force Git to accept my commit before `1970`? I remember I did it sometime, but using an older version of git. Currently I'm using `git version 2.1.4`. Maybe changing the source code and recompiling my own `git` will work?

<sub>I need this for experimental reasons–just in case some of you will ask *why*. :)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't yet possible, as I mentioned in "[Is it possible to set a git commit to have a timestamp prior to 1970?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24977895/6309)"

You can store a date prior to 1970, but you cannot guarantee that it will be correctly represented.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I *store* it?

Comment: @IonicăBizău You have some techniques to store a timestamp discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24977895/6309.

Comment: Yeah, got it! :) Thanks!