# How can I determine the date of GIT cherry pick?

Tags: git

Suppose I:

1. Pushed some file to branch A.
2. Cherry picked the commit from branch A to branch B.

Once I enter git log -1 on branch B, I can see that the date is the original one in which the file was pushed to branch A.

So how can I determine the cherry pick date?

Thanks,

Qwerty

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A git commit has two dates. One is the **author date** and the other is the **commit date**. The default display is the author date. You want the commit date. `git log -1 --pretty=fuller` will show that or you can use *%cD* in a log format.

Answer (score 1):

You can force both the author date and the commit date of a cherry-picked commit using something like

% GIT_AUTHOR_DATE='<desired author date>' GIT_COMMITTER_DATE='<desired committer date>' git cherry-pick <your commit hash>

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19742762/334942) details the formats that you can use for the two date parameters.