# How to parse default git date format in C#

Tags: c#, git, datetime, string-parsing

How do you parse the default git format to a DateTime in C#?
As per [What is the format for --date parameter of git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742345/what-is-the-format-for-date-parameter-of-git-commit)

The default date format from git looks like `Mon Jul 3 17:18:43 2006 +0200`.

Right now I don't have control over the output, this strings comes from another tool that printed the date and I need to parse it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't parse this to `DateTime`, I would parse it to [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx) since it has a [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) value inside of it.

Why? Because if you parse it to `DateTime`, you will get a `DateTime` as `Local` and it *might* generate different results for different machines since they *can* have timezone offsets of *that* time.

For example, I'm in [Istanbul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istanbul) and we use [Eastern European Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/eet) which use UTC+02:00. If I run the example of your code with `ParseExact` method, I will get the `07/03/2006 18:18:43` as a `Local` time.

Why? Because in 3 July 2006, [my timezone was in a daylight saving time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/turkey/istanbul?syear=2000&eyear=2009) which is UTC+03:00. That's why it generates `1` hour forwarded result. That's the part makes it ambiguous when you parse it to `DateTime`.

```
string s = "Mon Jul 3 17:18:43 2006 +0200";
DateTimeOffset dto;
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(s, "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy K", 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                 DateTimeStyles.None, out dto))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dto);
}
```

Now, you have a `DateTimeOffset` as `07/03/2006 17:18:43 +02:00`. You can still get the `DateTime` part with it's [`.DateTime` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.datetime.aspx) but it's [`Kind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will be `Unspecified` in that case.

But of course, I suggest to use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) instead which can solve most of the DateTime weirdness.

Comment: Thanks, in my case I didn't need to be very precise in the parsing and it is for a tool in a team all working in the same timezone. However, I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best format string I found is `ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy K`.

```
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    gitDateString,
    "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy K",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
    out date
);
```