# GitHub commit log seems inconsistent with respect to commit dates

Tags: github, push, commit, git-commit

Today is December 16, 2017. I just screen-snipped this GitHub commit log:
[image: Screen Snip from GitHub commit log]

If today is 12/16, why does a commit from 12/14 appear as 5 days ago?

Comment: Your commit `84993b3` have `AuthorDate: Mon Dec 11 10:54:26 2017 -0500` and `CommitDate: Thu Dec 14 17:47:25 2017 -0500`. Probably you rebase or cherry-pick them.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Hey, how did you know that? OP didn't include a link...

Comment: @einpoklum Use [the Search](https://www.github.com/search?q=84993b3&type=Commits), Luke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the commits were made 5 or 7 days ago, but you only `git push`ed them to GitHub on the 14th.

Answer (score 2):

As @einpoklum has mentioned, you committed and pushed on different days.

Although it is not advised to do it frequently, if you must change the date, then you can do so by passing the `--date` flag when running `git commit`.  For information on formatting, you can check out this link, [what-is-the-format-for-date-parameter-of-git-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742345/what-is-the-format-for-date-parameter-of-git-commit)